Customizing format of rlang::abort message
I am trying to customize the bullets of rlang::abort. I followed the guide ltter by letter, yet I still get the default bullets both in the native R console as well as the Rstudio console. What am I overlooking?
options(cli.user_theme = list(
  ".cli_rlang .bullet-*" = list(before = "* "),
  ".cli_rlang .bullet-i" = list(before = "* "),
  ".cli_rlang .bullet-x" = list(before = "* "),
  ".cli_rlang .bullet-v" = list(before = "* "),
  ".cli_rlang .bullet->" = list(before = "* ")
))

rlang::abort(c(
  "The error message.",
  "*" = "Regular bullet.",
  "i" = "Informative bullet.",
  "x" = "Cross bullet.",
  "v" = "Victory bullet.",
  ">" = "Arrow bullet."
))

yields the following 2 results (native console and RStudio console):


Session Info
─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
 os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
 system   x86_64, mingw32
 ui       Rgui
 language EN
 collate  German_Germany.utf8
 ctype    German_Germany.utf8
 tz       Europe/Berlin
 date     2024-12-02
 pandoc   3.2 @ <Path 1>

─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date (UTC) lib source
 cli           3.6.3   2024-06-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.2)
 rlang         1.1.4   2024-06-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.2)
 sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)

 [1] <Path 2>
 [2] <Path 3>

──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


I think you need to have options(cli.condition_unicode_bullets = FALSE) set as well as was done earlier in the examples on that linked page.

Thanks for the hint, but I have tried that as well and it did have no impact, besides replacing the unicode bullets by ascii bullets (as the option suggests).
